# Typhoon defaultAssembly() in Swift

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am having problem implementing defaultAssembly() for my swift application. I need to access one of the dependencies directly from a legacy code.

The application is fully typhoon integrated - with Plist initialization and Storyboards.

The first problem was to set the assembly as default one because it's created automatically from plist. In the end I just made it default after activation. I don't know whether it's a correct way but it appears to be working.

```
public override func activate() -> AppAssembly! {
    var instance = super.activate() as! AppAssembly
    instance.makeDefault()
    return instance
}
```

The real problem is when I retrieve it like this:

```
var assembly = TyphoonAssembly.defaultAssembly() as! AppAssembly
```

I get an error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'TyphoonBlockComponentFactory' (0x10f78bc40) to 'AppAssembly'
```

How should I then retrieve it? Or do I set the default assembly wrong?

Thanks
Tomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - that is not the correct way to make a default assembly using plist integration.

Rather than make a *new* assembly as shown above, take the one that was declared in the plist and make it the default. To do this:

```
public dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("assembly", with: self)
    }
}
```

And then in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     self.assembly.makeDefault()
 }
```

Unfortunately though, this won't solve your problem with cast - it looks like the Swift type system is obstructing things - this has been logged as a bug. In the meantime, please use:

```
var factory = TyphoonComponentFactory.defaultFactory()
var something = factory.componentForKey("someKey")
```

. . . where key is the name of a method in any of your assemblies.